# Populate Dropdown from JSON Data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to populate my dropdown menu with the information data in my js file. Each time i click on the button, 3 objects are added to the dropdown. I only want the three to show whenever I click. I am also getting just [object object], no real value. What am I missing?

index.js

```
const information = [
{
"gender": "prefer not to say",
"age": "20"
},
{
"gender": "female",
"age": "9"
},
{
"gender": "male",
"age": "18"
}
];

  const dropDownDisplay = () => {
        
    for(i=0; i<information.length; i++){
  
      const item = document.createElement("a");
      item.setAttribute("class","dropdown-item");
      item.href = "#"; 
      const node = document.createTextNode(information[i]); 
      item.appendChild(node);
      document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu')[0].appendChild(item);
      console.log(item)
  
    }
  }

  const dropdownMenuButton = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton");
dropdownMenuButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => dropDownDisplay());

}
```

index.html

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
Info:
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVRe1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it is fine now. For future - if you pass object, you need to specify which key/value pair you need (Example: information[i].gender). Otherwise will get a reference to an object [object Object]
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Info:
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu d-none" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">123</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">123</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">123</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
const information = 
[
  {
    "gender": "prefer not to say",
    "age": "20",
  },
  {
    "gender": "female",
    "age": "9",
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "age": "18",
  }
];

const dropDownDisplay = () => {
  for (i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
    const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu')
    if(dropdown.classList.contains('d-none'))
    {
      dropdown.classList.add('d-block')
      dropdown.classList.remove('d-none')
    }
    else{
      dropdown.classList.add('d-none')
      dropdown.classList.remove('d-block')
    }
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item');
    items[i].textContent = `${information[i].gender} ${information[i].age}`;
  }
};

const dropdownMenuButton = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton");
dropdownMenuButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => dropDownDisplay());
```

Comment: The policies was an error. It should be information[i] (Fixed that).

Comment: You can't pass object directly on textContent, because your information stored not in information[i] object, but in key/value pairs (gender and age). So you need to specify what key/value pair you using. I will edit my code in few minutes

Comment: nothing changes on the UI, and console.log(items) returns ```.dropdown-item``` and not the value

Comment: Sorry, i was sleeping. I finally understood what you mean (sorry I'm kinda dumb). Check the answer again